# Oracle DATE and Hibernate/JPA mapping

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, spring-data-jpa

One of the Oracle tables looks like this, I dont have the option of changing this:

```
REPORTING_PERIOD | REPORTING_DATE (Oracle DATE type)
-------------------------------
1140               01-FEB-12
1139               01-JAN-12
```

The JPA entity (with Hibernate as the provider) which looks like this :

```
@Column(name="REPORTING_PERIOD")
private long reportingPeriod;

@Temporal( TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name="REPORT_DATE")
private Date reportDate; //java.util.Date
```

Now, let us go through my unit tests:
(I am using Spring Data JPA for repositories)
The below line queries the DB by REPORTING_PERIOD column

```
ReportingPeriod period1 = reportingPeriodRepository.findByMaxReportingPeriod();
assertNotNull(period1); // works fine and entity is fetched
System.out.println(period1.getReportDate());
```

The out put of SOP is **2012-02-01** - Notice the automatic conversion from value in db **01-FEB-12**

Now, If I query directly by date using '01-FEB-12', as I am doing below, I dont get any results:

```
ReportingPeriod period2 = reportingPeriodRepository.findByReportDate(period1.getReportDate());
assertNotNull(period2);
```

Notice that, I am using date field from the same entity which I could successfully fetch in the previous statement.

Nor this works :

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
ReportingPeriod period3 = reportingPeriodRepository.findByReportDate(df.parse("2012-02-01"));
assertNotNull(period3);
```

Any help on how can I query ( with HQL will also be ok) by REPORTING_DATE as the param when the value in db is 01-FEB-12 is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the format you are using is correct to parse the string to `Date`? Can you try `DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`?

Comment: @βнɛƨн Ǥʋяʋиɢ -- Nope, I had actually tried that earlier too, but does not work. Strangely, Hibernate does not report any errors, only no results.

Comment: Can you give us the query (`NamedQuery` or Critera query or whatever it is you use.) I think the error/problem is in the query or in the method findByReportDate

Comment: Here it is :  @Query("FROM ReportingPeriod R where R.reportDate = ?1")
 ReportingPeriod findByReportDate(Date reportDate);

Comment: The autogenerated hibernate SQL : org.hibernate.SQL - select * from ( select reportingp0_.REPORTING_PERIOD as REPORTING1_3_, reportingp0_.REP_TIMESTAMP as REP2_3_, reportingp0_.REPORT_DATE as REPORT3_3_ from IR_REPORTING_PERIOD reportingp0_ where reportingp0_.REPORT_DATE=? ) where rownum <= ?

Comment: try a date range from >= 2012-02-01 to < 2012-02-02 in your query and see if that brings any results.  sometimes with dates, you think you're working with a date and its really storing it as a date-time

Comment: I think like @BruceLowe, Oracle **always** stores dates with time (even if you don't show it). If you can query the DB with pure sql (not with hibernate) see what you get for this query: `select to_char(REPORTING_DATE, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') from IR_REPORTING_PERIOD`

Comment: +1 to @BruceLowe Lowe and @A.B.Cade; it did the trick!! It indeed was storing DateTime

Answer (score 3):

I think there is some explicit date format conversion while obtaining the result in reportingPeriodRepository.findByMaxReportingPeriod();

Hence we can check whether we get the data using the same format as database format

Change

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
ReportingPeriod period3 = reportingPeriodRepository.findByReportDate(df.parse("2012-02-01"))
```

to

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy"); 
ReportingPeriod period3 = reportingPeriodRepository.findByReportDate(df.parse("01-FEB-12"))
```